# Review guidelines for new and late posts

Tags: discussion, support

I have read following posts regarding review tasks

[Is it okay to just say “no action needed” if a post in the review queue has already been edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161429/is-it-okay-to-just-say-no-action-needed-if-a-post-in-the-review-queue-has-alre)

[What are the limits on using the “no action needed” button in the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158764/what-are-the-limits-on-using-the-no-action-needed-button-in-the-review-queue)

[What to do when reviewing a good Q/A?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5831/what-to-do-when-reviewing-a-good-q-a)

[Processing the Review / Late Answers queue](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4005/processing-the-review-late-answers-queue)

and this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160314/are-posts-removed-from-the-review-queue-if-they-get-a-no-action-needed-review)

and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158983/both-no-action-needed-and-im-done-enabled-when-reviewing-a-post-for-the-sec)

and [this](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/review-etiquette-re-obviously-incorrect-or-irrelevant-answers)

When I review a post I look for the following basic criteria:

1. It should not be a spam
2. Question should be relevant to the forum
3. Answer should be an answer (not another question)
4. If any edits are required to improve the structure of the post

I do flag if the post needs attention (not an answer, spam, off topic, etc). I do edit the post if it needs an edit. If the post doesn't need attention, I click "no action needed".

Am I doing something wrong by clicking "no action needed" if the post passes above four tests?

Do I need to do more checks? If yes, are they documented somewhere or am I not looking hard enough?

Is is mandatory for me to vote the post up or down if I don't feel it is needed?

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing the same as you. When an edit already is submitted there's no action needed from *you* anymore, since your task is already done by someone else.